# jQuery dataTables sorting on custom date range column

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTable and the first column contain a custom date range. For ex: `22 Oct 2015 - 22 Nov 2015` where `22 Oct 2015` is the start date and `22 Nov 2015` is the end date. I want the sorting functionality to work on start date.

Let me explain a scenario: Let say I have 4 rows in DataTable and the first column date values are:

- 25 Aug 2016 - 21 Sep 2016
- 22 Oct 2015 - 22 Nov 2015
- 21 Oct 2015 - 21 Nov 2015
- 02 Dec 2015 - 02 Jan 2016

I want the sorting result in following format:

- 25 Aug 2016 - 21 Sep 2016
- 02 Dec 2015 - 02 Jan 2016
- 22 Oct 2015 - 22 Nov 2015
- 21 Oct 2015 - 21 Nov 2015

How to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must implement your own sorting plugin to do that. It is quite simple :

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "date-range-pre": function ( a ) {
        a = a.split('-')[0].trim();
        return Date.parse(a);   
    },
     "date-range-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
     "date-range-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
} );
```

The above simply extracts the first date by splitting the string and then do the sorting on that. There is no error handling, i.e care taking of empty strings and so on - you can do that yourself. Usage :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
       { type: 'date-range', targets: 0 }
    ]
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/gs5syg70/**

Comment: Asc sorting is simple as `return b - a` and desc sorting would be `return a - b;` (or may be it is the other way round but you get the point).